# how does "pointInside:" work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

I'm doing some hit testing and have run into a confusing situation.

I have two buttons "favoriteButton" and "shareButton". The following code results in 'a' and 'b' being true even though the buttons do not overlap:

```
CGPoint dunno = CGPointMake(11, 7);

BOOL a = [self.favoriteButton pointInside:dunno withEvent:nil];
BOOL b = [self.shareButton pointInside:dunno withEvent:nil];
```

and just to prove it, here is the description output for the two buttons at the point that this code is being called.

```
Printing description of _favoriteButton:
<UIButton: 0x5da8c90; frame = (10 6; 37 35); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x5da8d40>>
Printing description of _shareButton:
<UIButton: 0x5da7150; frame = (46 6; 30 35); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x5da59b0>>
```

Whats going on here? Am I misunderstanding what the output should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well @Nippysaurus according to the documentation

http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/pointInside:withEvent:

```
A point that is in the receiver’s local coordinate system (bounds).
```

That means that point `CGPoint dunno = CGPointMake(11, 7);` is inside the view as the bounds of the view will be different that the frame of the same view.